# A complex scenario for elasticsearch watcher plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, alert, correlation, elasticsearch-plugin

I need to learn the boundary of elasticsearch watcher plugin. I need to make an alert for matching results of multiple queries. For example, can it alert for a scenario like that:

1. Get ip results from query1 as ip1, ip2, .., ipN ;
2. Get mac results from query2 as mac1, mac2, .., macN ;
3. Get hostname results query3 as hostname1, hostname2, .., hostnameN;
4. Match these entries with a join type(or table) having fields ip, mac, hostname then alert for entries satisfying at least two queries.
5. Run this scenario for each last n minutes

Note: query1, query2 and query3 are queries with filter and aggregation which answer a question like ip addresses had failed logins more than m in last n minutes

let's explain more concretely,

***query results are below:***

```
ip results from query1       -> ip1
mac results from query2      -> mac2
hostname results from query3 -> hostname2, hostname3
```

***join table(or type) is below:***

```
ip      mac     hostname   
--      ---     --------  
ip1     mac1    hostname1  -> computer1

ip2     mac2    hostname2  -> computer2

ip3     mac3    hostname3  -> computer3
```

If you look at join table and query results,

```
ip1 belongs to computer1 so computer1 satisfies query1
mac2 and hostname2 belongs to computer2 so computer2 satisfies query2 and query3
hostname3 belongs to computer3 so computer3 satisfies query3
```

so, send an email for user related to computer2 which satisfies at least two queries(query2 and query3).

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Can you be more elaborate on your example

Comment: I tried, is it clear enough ?

Comment: @vineeth-mohan can you look again ?